# My "Ignored Tag" questions are no longer rendering grayed out

Tags: support, ignored-tags

I'm not sure when this happened but recently (January 2014) I've noticed that my ignored tags on StackOverflow are no longer visually grayed out/washed out.

I'm not sure if this was an intentional change or an oversight but I miss the feature.

Update: To clarify this is on the main "recent" questions list page. (sadly if I try to visit the "winforms" tag page... everything is 100% opaque (as expected) so it can be hard to test ;-)

Comment: Maybe you are in a specific ignored tag page? In such case it's pointless to grey out *all* questions.

Comment: No, this is on the main list of recent questions.

Comment: Well, for me it's not showing any question with ignored tag at all. So you say you see questions with tags you ignore appear without any special color? Can you post screenshot?

Comment: Under User » Preferences (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/<your-user-id>), there are two options for ignored tags. *Gray out* and *hide*. Did you check that you do not hide them?

Comment: @FallenAngel doh! that's it! though I don't recall that option ever being available before (nor do I recall setting it). I'll close this question now.

Comment: Ok the I will post it as an answer, maybe in the future someone else may need it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under `User » Preferences` (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current), there are two options for ignored tags. *Gray out* and *hide*. Check that you do not hide them.